# Ising model with quantum magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, ising-model

Hamiltonian of the Ising model with an external magnetic field is written as
$$H=-J\sum_{\langle i,j \rangle} s_i s_j + h\sum_j s_j$$
where $J$ is nearest neighbor coupling constant and $h$ is the external magnetic field. As far as I know, the external magnetic field $h$ is always treated as a classical field while solving this system. I want to write above Hamiltonian such that $h$ is being treated as a quantum field. How can I do that?

I do not know what am I asking, the only thing that I want to solve is that "what happens if we treat the external magnetic field as a quantum field instead of a classical field?"

Comment: Do you want to create your own model?

Comment: @AlexTrounev kind of yes.

Comment: I searched on google and find [1] that a Classical field theory can be converted into quantum field theory by two methods i) path integrals ii) Canonical commutation relations. But here I just want to convert $h$-field into quantum field.
[1] https://www.quora.com/How-do-we-turn-a-classical-field-theory-into-a-quantum-field-theory

Comment: You can of course promote $h$ to be an operator, i.e., send $h \to B S^z$ where $B$ is another real number and $S^z$ some operator. However the way you would solve this model is simply diagonalize the quantum part separately, i.e., go to the space where $S^z = m$ where The eigenvalue $m$ is a real number. This simply sends $h \to m B$. If you really want to have a non-trivial model you need to include the quantum terms that generate the quantum magnetization.

Comment: (Continued..) Yet again, there cannot be no entanglement between a classical system and a quantum one so even this last prescription would be solved trivially, I.e., the quantum model would be solved separately.

Comment: @LuqmanSaleem in quantum electrodynamics, the vector potential is used to describe the electromagnetic field.